# Of parallel texts, lists and display equations

Tags: equations, lists, two-column, parallel

In previous [question concerned about taking notes while reading journal articles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8996/791), I received an excellent answer proposing the use of `parallel`, `parcolumns`, and `ledpar` packages. However, I have the following problems with these packages:

**parallel:**
Doesn't play well with `itemize` and `enumerate` environments.
*New info:* Also creates an undesired vertical space on the non-equation column when using a display equation environment (see also illustration for `parcolumns` farther below).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=0.3in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=0.3in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{parallel}

\begin{document}
  \begin{Parallel}{3in}{3in}
    \ParallelLText{\lipsum[1]}
    \ParallelRText{\lipsum[2]
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Hello World!
        \item Yeah!
        \item Hi there!
      \end{itemize}}
    \ParallelPar
  \end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**parcolumns:**
Using `displaymath` and similar environments (in this case `IEEEeqnarray`) causes an undesired vertical space before the equation, even affecting the other column:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=0.3in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=0.3in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{parcolumns}

\begin{document}
  \begin{parcolumns}[rulebetween=true]{2}
    \colchunk[1]{\lipsum[1]}
    \colchunk[2]{\lipsum[2]
      \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
        E & = & mc^2
      \end{IEEEeqnarray}
      Some useful greetings:
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Hello World!
        \item Yeah!
        \item Hey there!
      \end{enumerate}}
  \end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ledpar:**
It simply didn't typeset my text in two columns. Did I miss something?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=0.3in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=0.3in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ledmac}
\usepackage{ledpar}

\begin{document}
  \begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
      \lipsum[1]
      \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
        E & = & mc^2
      \end{IEEEeqnarray}
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
      \lipsum[2]
    \end{Rightside}
    \Columns
  \end{pairs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I think I favor the `parallel` package overall. I just wish I could get around the `itemize`/`enumerate` problem. Any other tips?

Comment: If you use `pdfcolparallel` instead of `parallel`, the `itemize` problem disappears, but you also get the ugly vertical space in front before equations...

Comment: @Jake: I just found out that an undesired vertical space (even on the non-equation column) occurs with `parallel` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go with [celenius' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8996/taking-notes-while-reading-a-journal-paper/9038#9038) to your [old question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8996/791) and use the [`tufte-latex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/) package, those problems don't appear. With its narrower right hand column and smaller font size, it's probably even better suited to your task of taking notes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,justified]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\marginnote{Here's some text that goes on the right side of the page. We'll make it long enough so the line wraps.
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
        E & = & mc^2
      \end{IEEEeqnarray}
      Some useful greetings:
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Hello World!
        \item Yeah!
        \item Hey there!
      \end{itemize}
}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: tufte-handout document with list and equation in the margin]

With a bit of tweaking, you can also get equal column widths and font sizes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,justified]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}

\geometry{textwidth=0.4\paperwidth}
\geometry{marginparwidth=\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\footnotesize{\normalsize}
\lipsum[2]
\marginnote{Here's some text that goes on the right side of the page. We'll make it long enough so the line wraps.
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
        E & = & mc^2
      \end{IEEEeqnarray}
      Some useful greetings:
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Hello World!
        \item Yeah!
        \item Hey there!
      \end{itemize}
}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: tufte_handout document with equal column widths and text sizes]

Comment: +1 @Jake: I appreciate the demo `:)`. Unfortunately, the two parallel texts don't align well at the top edge. I was also looking for something like, what if my `marginnote` is longer vertically than the main text that it is `marginnote`-ing? I would want that the next chunk of main text would `vskip` to the bottom of the previous `marginnote`. I just might have to try the `longtable` environment.

Comment: In the `tufte-latex` classes, the margin notes are designed so that the baseline of the first line of the margin note aligns with the baseline of the text it was called from.  If the margin note is longer than the main text, it will continue past the main text (and can even run off the page). This is something I hope to correct in a future version. Given that you want the next main text paragraph to start after the end of the longest block of text (main or margin note), it would seem that `\marginnote` isn't what you're looking for.