# eledpar — parallel columns not being set

Tags: columns, parallel, eledpar

I am trying to use `eledpar` to typeset paragraphs in two languages in parallel, in columns on the same page, but am having no success. Minimal working example:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt,asymmetric]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

 \begin{pairs}
  \begin{Leftside}{\lipsum[1]}
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}{\lipsum[1]}
  \end{Rightside}
  \Columns
 \end{pairs}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is the output: [image]

---

Version and environment:

Mac OS: `10.8.4`

eledmac:

```
revision:    31251
cat-version: 1.5/1.4
cat-date:    2013-07-20 17:09:33 +0200
```

---

Note: This issue was raised among several others in a [post from 2011](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9105/of-parallel-texts-lists-and-display-equations) but doesn't seem to have been answered there.

Comment: Try [`paracol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) package...

Comment: Thanks, @karlkoeller. In the end I settled on `longtable` for my current project. But I would like to understand why what I have done with `ledpar` isn't working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The eledpar package must be used in combination with command of the eledmac package. These commands are :

- \beginnumbering \endnumbering to set a numbered text.
- \pstart \pend to set a unit. These unit are to be defined to allow to have the right //ism.

So, in your case

```
\begin{pairs}

\begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
        \pstart
            \lipsum[1]
    \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}  
    \beginnumbering
        \pstart
            \lipsum[1]
        \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\Columns
\end{pairs}
```

See the ¶ 2.1 of eledpar documentation.

Comment: So these are not optional. I had assumed that since I don't want numbering, I could just omit them, but now I see (actually in ¶ 2 of the docs), that only numbered text is set in parallel. That had not been clear at all!

Comment: If you don't want numbering, you can use the option \numberlinefalse (see ¶3.1 of the eledmac documentation). But the pstart system is need to have the right //ism ... and the pstart system need beginnumbering.