# Getting Started with reledmac/reledpar Package (Parallel Text)

Tags: reledmac, reledpar, parallel-texts

I want to use the **parallel text** feature of the [reledpar](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledpar) package with requires the [reledmac](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledmac) as far as I understand.

I tried the very basic example from the documentation ([reledpar](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledpar), page 8) and I get an error message.

Before you want to compile my example make sure that your **system** is **updated**. The packages are pretty new.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        Text left.
    \end{Leftside}
    %
    \begin{Rightside}
        Text right.
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

> ! Package reledpar Error: \Columns called without previous `pairs`
>   environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message is not good. But the problem is that you need `\beginnumbering\pstart\pend\endnumbering`, as explained in the handbook of reledpar §3, you need to use the reledmac numbering system.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Text left.
            \pend
         \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    %
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Text right
            \pend
         \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

See also the examples in reledmac distribution. Note that it is a duplicated of [eledpar — parallel columns not being set](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127752/eledpar-parallel-columns-not-being-set)

ps: the next version of reledmac/reledpar, normally published tomorrow, will have a more acute message.

Comment: A **\pend** was missing, I changed the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The example code in the **reledpar** documentation (page 8) is not correct then?

Comment: I have trouble to understand the true purpose of the reledmac/reledpar packages. Is there a (large/complex) example document available showing some of the features?

Comment: @Maneul Kuehner: the code is shortened, because it explain only the parallel typesetting, not the numbering system, which you need to use it, as explained in § 3. And as explained in introduction of reledmac handbook, you have a "example" folder with many example of feature of the package.

Comment: `(re)ledmac`'s goal is to facilitate the production of criticial editions, especially the critical apparatus as produced traditionally by textual scholarship/philology. `(re)ledpar` extends this to parallel texts, usually source text and translation, but possibly also two (main) text witnesses. If this isn't what you are aiming at, there is a certain danger that you'll be hindered by the restrictions that `(re)ledmac/par` have imposed to achieve their main purpose, while many of their features will be superfluous for you.

Comment: I ran this, and I noticed that there is no automatic linebreaking. Is there a way to have automatic line breaks?

Comment: what do you mean? reledmac break lines normally...