# Writing parallel texts using \memorydump

Tags: xetex, reledmac, reledpar, ledmac

I Want to write two parallels texts. I can do it this way :

```
\begin{document}
  \begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
     \beginnumbering
     \pstart
      TEXT
     \pend
     \endnumbering
   \end{Leftside}
   \begin{Rightside}
     \beginnumbering
      \pstart
       TRANSLATION
      \pend
      \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
  \end{pairs}
\Columns
\end{document}
```

But it does not work when I write :

```
\begin{document}

    \begin{pairs}
        \begin{Leftside} \beginnumbering
         \pstart
          TEXT
         \pend
        \end{Leftside}
    
        \begin{Rightside} \beginnumbering
            \pstart
             TRANSLATION
             \pend
        \end{Rightside}
    \end{pairs}
   \Columns

    \begin{pairs}
        \begin{Leftside} \memorydump
            \pstart
             TEXT
            \pend
          \endnumbering \end{Leftside}
            \begin{Rightside} \memorydump
            \pstart
            \pend
           \endnumbering    \end{Rightside}
          \end{pairs}
          \Columns
\end{document}
```

I guess the problem must come from `\memorydump`, but I don't get why.

Comment: Did you really check that the structure of your document is correct? See this answer as reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308318/47927 . You write that you don't forget `\endnumbering`, why don't you put it in the code of your example then? In order to help you, it would be best to have a minimal (non-)working example. Also, what is `\renewcommand{\Rlineflag}{}` supposed to do?

Comment: if you only show a fragment of your code and do not say what errors you get from your full code, it is very hard to help.

Comment: I edited the post. I hope it's better now.

Comment: Jasper Habict : ```\renewcommand{\Rlineflag}{}``` is supposed to delete the line numbering for the page on the right side. I don't need line numbers for the translation.

Comment: You have to close all environments carefully. Two things made it work for me: (1) call \Columns outside pairs-environment. (2) Close the numbering sections with \endnumbering

Comment: It works fin when I do what mxordn tells me, but it does not work when I use \memorydump. However, this is a command I need.

Comment: @happybobby you still have not posted an example document, nor said what error you got.

Answer (score 1):

### **tl;dr**

Dump `\memorydump` (which doesn't interact optimally with `reledmac`) and use `\pausenumbering` and `\resumenumbering` instead (see `reledmac`manual §5.2.7 and [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653249/)).

---

Your use of `\memorydump` appears functionally equivalent to the very skimpy example **in the "manual"** part of the `reledpar` documentation (§7.2). In fact, the "official" example doesn't compile either. The bad form consists in **removing an `\endnumbering` before closing `Leftside`** which, however, is what the manual shows us to do. It also tells us to place a `\memorydump` first thing in the next `Leftside` environment.

What does `\memorydump` do? According to the "code" part of the documentation (§III, p. 37):

> `\memorydump` is a shorthand for `\pausenumbering\resumenumbering`. This will clear the memorised stuff for the previous chunks while keeping the numbering going.

Basically, *to call `\memorydump` is to call `\endnumbering` and `\beginnumbering` directly after one another*. But then, *no matter where you place `\memorydump`,* you mess with the very delicate hierarchy and arrangement of environments that is needed to operate `reledpar`. No matter where you use it, it will break things.

It is hard to tell from the question what you are actually trying to achieve. (Please clarify the question, if you are still interested.)

**Assuming** your aim is to preserve continuous line numbering across a "break" – meaning that you break down long chunks of texts by ending the `Leftside and pages (etc.) environments and printing the \Pages every once in a while, allowing for more natural page breaks and text distribution – then the solution is the same as detailed in [my other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653249/).

Just before the break, use `\pausenumbering` instead of `\endnumbering` and right after, use `\resumenumbering` instead of `\beginnumbering` (these are explained in the `reledmac`manual §5.2.7).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}   % just for the screenshots
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[series={A},noend, noeledsec, noledgroup, nopenalties]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
%
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
%
%\endnumbering     % endnumbering --> resets line counting
\pausenumbering    % pausenumbering --> continuous numbering
\end{Leftside}
%
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
%
\pstart
\blindtext
\blindtext
\pend
%
%\endnumbering     % endnumbering --> resets line counting
\pausenumbering    % pausenumbering --> continuous numbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
%\beginnumbering     % beginnumbering --> restarts line numbering from 1 here
\resumenumbering     % resumenumbering --> continuous numbering
%
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
%
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
%\beginnumbering     % beginnumbering --> restarts line numbering from 1 here
\resumenumbering     % resumenumbering --> continuous numbering
%
\pstart
\blindtext
\blindtext
\pend
%
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

[image: first two pages with continued numbering]
[image: latter two pages with continued numbering]
[image: another two pages with continued numbering]

Comment: +1: Great answer!