# \memorydump command not working in parallel pages text

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610649/writing-parallel-texts-using-memorydump) that is very similar to mine, but it was not properly answered (I guess because it was poorly explained), so I'll try and ask again: if the moderation thinks that this is a duplicate, I would be happy to close it, as long as the other question get answered! :)

Anyway.

I have a parallel text to be written in two pages. On the left side there is a latin text and on the right side the vulgarization of it, and the notes are basically all on the vulgarization (there is a critical family also dedicated to the latin text, but is almost unused). This create a strong unbalance between the notes, and if remaining within the same `Leftside` and `Rightside`, `reledpar` starts to have problems. I wanted then to split the text by using `\memorydump`. Unfortunately, I keep obtaining mysterious errors.

I'll provide the most minimal example I'm able to write:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}[Numbers=OldStyle]

\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[series={A},noend, noeledsec, noledgroup, nopenalties]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
            \beginnumbering
            \pstart
            \blindtext
            \pend
            
            \pstart
            \blindtext
            \pend
            % \endnumbering  % <-- I understood that I have to comment this to make \memorydump work
        \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
            \pstart
            \blindtext
            \pend
            
            \pstart
            \blindtext
            \pend
            % \endnumbering  % <-- I understood that I have to comment this to make \memorydump work
        \end{Rightside}
    \end{pages}
    \Pages
    
    \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
            \memorydump
            % \beginnumbering  % <-- and also this
            \pstart
            \blindtext
            \pend
            
            \pstart
            \blindtext
            \pend
            \endnumbering
        \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}
            \memorydump
            % \beginnumbering  % <-- and also this
            \pstart
            \blindtext
            \pend
            
            \pstart
            \blindtext
            \pend
            \endnumbering
        \end{Rightside}
    \end{pages}
    \Pages
    
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the process breaks down. I tried all the combinations I could think of:
commenting `\beginnumbering` and `\endnumbering`, uncommenting them, placing `\memorydump` before or after `\beginnumbering` and removing or leaving `\end{pages}\Pages\begin{pages}` in the middle.

Every time the errors are different and, while they all make sense on their own, I still don't understand what should I do and what should be the right way to use this feature. Of course, removing `\memorydump` makes everything work again, but the line numbering of the new paragraph restarts from 1 and I don't want this.

I am referring to §7.2 (page 17) of the `relepar` documentation.

Comment: Your use of `\memorydump` fits the description in the "manual" part of the documentation (§7.2). And your example appears functionally equivalent to the one there. In fact, that "official" example (when completed) doesn't compile for me. Same errors as with your MWE.

Comment: But taking a hint from the "code" part of the documentation (§III, p. 37): "`\memorydump` is a shorthand for `\pausenumbering\resumenumbering`. This will clear the memorised stuff for the previous chunks while keeping the numbering going.", one could try the following: *replace your commented-out `\endnumbering` with `\pausenumbering` and `\beginnumbering` with `\resumenumbering`. And dump `\memorydump`*. This allows for *continued numbering* in the next chunk of text. Is this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't use `reledpar` enough to tell whether I've overlooked something important – or whether there might be an error in the documentation or even a bug (!). But this point could be worth clarifying in the manual. Also, the `reledmac`/`reledpar` installation comes with a number of good sample `.tex` and `.pdf` documents, but alas, none of them exemplifies the use of `\memorydump`.

Comment: memorydump is a historical feature coming from the time computer had not so many memory. I don't think it was ported to ledpar.

But I thinks you should be more explicit about "reledpar starts to have problem". Maybe memorydump is not the best solution.

Comment: @Maïeul, I get too many errors to reproduce in a comment, but the first one is `\begin{Rightside} on input line 26 ended by \end{pages}.` Basically what you get if you forgot the `\endnumbering` in: `\pend` **`\endnumbering`** `\end{Rightside} \end{pages} \Pages`. And the remaining errors (wrong respective placement/hierarchy of numberings, pstarts, pages-environments...) just trickle from there. However, *this is how the manual advises to use `\memorydump`*. Maybe you could drop it from the manual and suggest using `\pausenumbering` – if @jschiavon can confirm that it works as desired...

Comment: Well, are you sur your code is well written. `\begin{Rightside} on input line 26 ended by \end{pages}` is quite explicit : your environement are not well nested.

Comment: @jschiavon: any new developments? did you try \pausenumbering out and did it help?

Comment: Sorry, I was away and without a laptop to test, indeed \pausenumbering works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The bad news:** `\memorydump` does not interact very well with `reledpar`.

**The good news:** There are better tools. `\pausenumbering` and `\resumenumbering` should to do the trick for you (`reledmac`manual §5.2.7).

### `\memorydump` doesn't help

Maïeul, the package maintainer, writes that the command is a relic of an older stage of `ledmac` and maybe was never ported to `(re)ledpar`.

It appears that you have done everything right: Your use of `\memorydump` **fits the description in the "manual"** part of the documentation (§7.2). And your example appears functionally equivalent to the very skimpy example there. In fact, the "official" example (when spelled out) doesn't compile either.

The program throws the same errors, the first error is:
`\begin{Rightside} on input line 26 ended by \end{pages}`
which is what you'd get if you forgot the `\endnumbering` in `\pend` **`\endnumbering`** `\end{Rightside} \end{pages} \Pages`.

In fact, this is what the manual and the example required us to do to use `\memorydump`. But by `reledpar` standards, closing a `Leftside` without closing the numbering is bad form and *must* produce an error!¹

As the "code" part of the documentation (§III, p. 37) notes,

> `\memorydump` is a shorthand for `\pausenumbering\resumenumbering`. This will clear the memorised stuff for the previous chunks while keeping the numbering going.

Those two commands in turn are just "softer" versions of `\endnumbering` and `\beginnumbering`: they have all the other functions, but they do not *reset* the line numbering.

*Hence, to call `\memorydump` is to call `\endnumbering` and `\beginnumbering` directly after one another*. But then, *no matter where you place `\memorydump`,* you mess with the very delicate hierarchy and arrangement of environments that is needed to operate `reledpar`. No matter where you use it, it will break things.

### `\pausenumbering` is the right tool

Your stated aim is to *break down chunks of texts* on the right side, which are consistently much longer than the left, to solve the imbalance.
And you do this by ending the `Leftside` and `pages` (etc.) environments and printing the `\Pages` every once in a while, allowing for more natural page breaks and text distribution.

To do this and preserve continuous line numbering, use the commands `\pausenumbering` and `\resumenumbering` instead of `\end`- and `\begin`- (`reledmac`manual §5.2.7).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}   % just for the screenshots
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[series={A},noend, noeledsec, noledgroup, nopenalties]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
%
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
%
%\endnumbering     % endnumbering --> resets line counting
\pausenumbering    % pausenumbering --> continuous numbering
\end{Leftside}
%
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
%
\pstart
\blindtext
\blindtext
\pend
%
%\endnumbering     % endnumbering --> resets line counting
\pausenumbering    % pausenumbering --> continuous numbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
%\beginnumbering     % beginnumbering --> restarts line numbering from 1 here
\resumenumbering     % resumenumbering --> continuous numbering
%
\pstart
\blindtext
\pend
%
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
%\beginnumbering     % beginnumbering --> restarts line numbering from 1 here
\resumenumbering     % resumenumbering --> continuous numbering
%
\pstart
\blindtext
\blindtext
\pend
%
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

[image: first two pages with continued numbering]
[image: latter two pages with continued numbering]
[image: another two pages with continued numbering]

---

1. I would suggest (to the maintainer) to revise the section of the manual on `\memorydump` which is giving wrong instructions.